# How to disable storyboard segue but still use segue identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

When I transition from a table view cell to another view controller, I can connect it on storyboard. However, this doesn't allow me to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method even when I want to use selected row and indexpath logic or pass a value between the two view controlelrs to make a transition.

But when I disable the storyboard segue transition, I cannot set segue identifier and hence cannot call `performSegueWithIndentifier:` method from within the above method.

So how can I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and still perform a segue? If I set my storyboard segue and at the same time define `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, my app crashes after I return back to the original view controller.

Comment: Is it just a simple push segue?

Comment: I cannot use both, right? When I tried to use both storyboard segue and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, my app got crashed.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath? You can do what you would normally do there, in prepareForSegue instead. If you need to decide which controller to segue to, then you need to connect the segues from the controller, not the cell, and apply your logic to determine which segue to call.

Comment: You don't need a segue, you can create a controller instance by identifier

Comment: rdelmar, since I want to use tapped cell information and change the second view controller's contents according to the tapped cell.

Comment: You can do that in prepareForSegue -- you don't need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all. The sender argument in prepareForSegue:sender: will be the cell you clicked on. You can get the indexPath from the table view method indexPathForCell:

Comment: You can also use indexPathForSelectedRow: on the UITableView. There's lots o' ways to get at the current row.

Comment: But do I still need storyboard segue identifier when I use multiple segue transitions, right? How can I know which segue to be called in `prepareForSegue: sender:`?

Comment: If you have more than one segue, then yes, you do need to use segue identifiers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create your segue from the viewControler button (yellow button on bottom) of viewControler1 to somewhere in the viewControler2